# mysql_fetch_assoc error when uploading to webhost godaddy

Tags: php, mysql

I have set up a content management system. It works fine on my local server, but when I upload it to Godaddy webhosting, I get an error on mysql_fetch_assoc() for a couple of query's. it says: "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter one to be resource". I know this commonly refers to an error in the mysql query. I don't know whether it is the connection with the database or maybe the webhost using another version of php? Can somebody help me? Here is the code for a query that gives an error:

```
function get_categories($id = null) {
$categories = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `naam` FROM `categori�n`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $categories[] = $row;
}
return $categories;
```

}

Comment: You could try to use `mysql_error` to find out why it went wrong.

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_xx()` functions are deprecated and their use is discouraged. You should consider switching to a more modern API like PDO as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your connection does not cascade into the function. You must pass the connection into the function.

```
function get_categories($id = null, $mysqlConnection) {
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the error is the weird character in the SQL statement. (�)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `naam` FROM `categori�n`");
```

Answer (score -2):

Dear bro you have error in query

$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,naam from categorion");

used this query